# Parse iOS SDK - Login using Mobile phone verification code like Watsapp

Tags: ios, parse-platform

How to implement login mechanism with mobile verification code.

**SignUp** (New User with New Mobile Number)

I can able to do this for signup user by generating a random password after verifying code send to his mobile number.

**Login** (Existing User with Mobile Number)
But don't knows how to implement this. I cant use changepassword method because it works only for an already logged in user.

**Setting the Current User**

Saw this Method in Parse Documentation. Can I use this method. If yes, how can I get session token.

```
[PFUser becomeInBackground:@"session-token-here" block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
  if (error) {
    // The token could not be validated.
  } else {
    // The current user is now set to user.
  }
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Successfully changed the password without login calling  cloud code from ios and then logged in with a new password.

**iOS Code**

```
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"assignPasswordToUser" withParameters:@{@"username":[self generateUsername],@"password":loginModel.verficationCode} block:^(id object, NSError *error) {

        if(!error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Assign New Password Success");
            [self doLogin];

        }else{
            NSLog(@"Assign New Password Failed");
            [self handError:error];
        }
    }];
```

**Cloud Code**

```
Parse.Cloud.define("assignPasswordToUser", function(request, response){
                   Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

                   var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
                   query.equalTo("username", request.params.username);

                   query.first({
                               success: function(theUser){
                               var newPassword = request.params.password;
                               console.log("New Password: " + newPassword);

                               console.log("set: " + theUser.set("password", newPassword));

                               theUser.save(null,{
                                            success: function(theUser){
                                            // The user was saved correctly
                                            response.success(1);
                                            },
                                            error: function(SMLogin, error){
                                            response.error("save failure");
                                            }
                                            });
                               },
                               error: function(error){
                               response.error("error");
                               }
                               });
                   });
```

Comment: Doesn't this mean someone could change someone else's password?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your wanted to allow something like registering a new device by scanning a QR Code or something shown on an existing device, you could do that without having to change the password as follows:

User class extra properties:

```
loginValidation: String
loginValidationExpiry: DateTime
```

You would use something like a 1 or 2 minute expiry to make things safer, making sure you create the Date using server-time in a Cloud Function. You could generate a guid/uuid for the code and create the QR code on an existing authenticated platform.

On the new device after reading the QR Code you could call this cloud function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("validateLoginCode", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Could.useMasterKey();

    var username = request.params.username;
    var validationCode = request.params.validationCode;

    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.equalTo("username", username);
    query.equalTo("loginValidation", validationCode);
    query.first({
        success: function(user) {
            if (user) {
                var expiry = user.get("loginValidationExpiry");
                var now = new Date();
                if (expiry > now) {
                    // code is valid, get token, only valid because
                    // we got user with master key
                    response.success({ token: user.getSessionToken() });
                } else {
                    response.error("code expired");
                }
            } else {
                response.error("invalid user/code");
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            response.error("error");
        }
    });
});
```

You could now use `becomeInBackground:block:` method in your calling code.